# Averaging nonzero values from INDEX and MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data in excel which has Time, Name, and Result columns.

My goal is to use formulas to generate a different, new table which shows the results for each Time (column) and Name (row) combination. This will later be used to generate a heatmap (the results are real numbers).

I am doing this by using a formula on each cell of the new table. An example from cell K5 in the new table is below:

```
=INDEX($AE$2:$AE$999, MATCH(1, INDEX(($A5=$X$2:$X$999)*(K$4=$V$2:$V$999),0,1),0))
```

Where `$AE$2:$AE$999` is the Result column, `$A5` is a name row in the new table, `$X$2:$X$999` is the Name column, `K$4` is a time column in the new table, and `$V$2:$V$999` is the Time column.

The problem is that my table of data has multiple entries that have identical Name and Time combinations, but differing Result values. For these combinations, I would like for the formula to return the average of all nonzero results.

I think the current formula only returns the first match it runs into. I would like for this process to be autmated as possible as the original table of data will be changed frequently.

Screenshot showing the two tables.

[image: Original table]

The new table. The formula shown in `G6` returns `0`. I would like for it to return the average of `3.1` and `2.6`.

[image]

Comment: Actual data would be helpful. One idea is to create a pivot table on your data which would sum your results by name and time. Then you can create your formulas and not worry about averaging results.

Answer (score 0):

***One note:** The text of your question is different from the images. I'm going to use the columns mentioned in the text of your message rather than the columns in the images.*

It looks like what you're doing is calculating an average but only under certain conditions. Since you're working with multiple conditions, you would start by looking at the formula AVERAGEIFS().

In your case, for Cell G5, You want the average if any row in column X is India (A5) and that same row in column V is 6 (G4) and that same row in column AE is not zero.

So, at its base, the formula in G5 would look like this:

```
= AVERAGEIFS(  $AE$2:$AE$999
             , $X$2:$X999, "=India"
             , $V$2:$V$999, "=6"
             , $AE$2:$AE$999, "<>0" )
```

However, you want it to be both dynamic and flexible, to do that and keep Excel from messing with things as I move cells around, I make extensive use of the ROW() AND COLUMN() functions.

I think the final might look something like this

```
= AVERAGEIFS( $AE$2:$AE$999
             , $X$2:$X$999, "=" & INDEX( $A:$A, ROW() )
             , $V$2:$V$999, "=" & INDEX( $4:$4, 1, COLUMN() )
             , $AE$2:$AE$999, "<>0" )
```

This can be pasted as is in any of the cells from B5 the the right and down, and should give you want you want in each cell. The formula will give you an error if the combination in the axes doesn't exist in the results table. So, you should wrap the whole thing in an error function and display what you want when that happens.

For reference

`INDEX( $A:$A, ROW() )` Gives you the label in column A for the row in which the formula resides. So, for any cell in Row 5, this is "India".

`INDEX( $4:$4, 1, COLUMN() )` gives you the label in row 4 for the column in which the formula resides. So, for any cell in column G, this will be "6".

Answer (score 0):

If you hace Excel Version 365, the Dynamic Array functions make this simple

[image]

Times formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(U:U,(ROW(U:U)>1)*(U:U<>"")))))
```

Names Formula

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(W:W,(ROW(W:W)>1)*(W:W<>""))))
```

Table formula

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(AD:AD,AD:AD,">0",U:U,C4#,W:W,B5#),"")
```

---

If you *don't* have 365, then the table formula can be

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($AD:$AD,$AD:$AD,">0",$U:$U,C$29,$W:$W,$B30),"")
```

and copied to the extents of the table.  Create the header row/column by any means you choose